# How to find all users by name?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
const author = mongoose.Schema(
  name: String,
 );
const listName = ["a","b","c","k"];
```

I have an array of names. How to find all user names?

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$in` operator.

```
author.find({ "name": { "$in": listName } },function(err,docs) {
      // code
});
```